# I have to maximize this function involving absolute values

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

f(x) = $\frac{1}{1+|x|}$ + $\frac{1}{1+|x-2|}$ needs to be maximized. Maximizing this function means minimizing the denominators simultaneously.

So I have to find the minimum value of 1+ $|x|$ and 1+ $|x-2|$ subjected to a single x. In this case, I see that x = 0 and x=2 are not going to work. Any value less than zero or greater than 2 is not going to work either. So some value of x in (0,2) is needed.

Comment: You mean "I have to find the maximum of this function..."

Comment: "Maximizing this function means minimizing the denominators simultaneously." Um, no. If you _could_ minimize both denominators at the same time, then, sure, that would maximize your function. But the opposite implication doesn't hold.

Comment: ohkay.. so I how to I go about this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Maximize **this** function you must minimize the denominators, so:

\begin{cases}
\lvert x \rvert = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0 \\
\lvert x - 2\rvert = 0 \Rightarrow x = 2
\end{cases}
For the two values of $x$  we have $f(0)=f(2) = \dfrac43$

Comment: hmm..  that makes sense..

Comment: This reasoning doesn't hold in general. _In this particular case_ it happens that the two maxima coincide by where one of the denominators is minimized, but for example $$g(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+(x-1)^2}$$ has a global maximum at $x=\frac12$ where _neither_ of the two denominators is minimal.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes it holds only in this case

Comment: @HenningMakholm: You can see that I write 'this function' I did not said that it holds in general case

Comment: @Navaro: Then you might as well have said, "to maximize this function, you must set $x=0$ or $x=2$", full stop. Or, "to maximize this function, you must solve $x^3-4x^2+4x=0$".

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Note: The tag says real-analysis, but I have done nothing fancy.

Upon close examination, we can see that there is a line of symmetry at $x=1$.

To confirm this, let us shift $f(x)$ by $1$ unit to the left.

$g(x)=f(x+1)=\dfrac{1}{1+|x+1|}+\dfrac{1}{1+|x-1|}$

Let $a>0$

$g(a)=\dfrac{1}{a+2}+\dfrac{1}{1+|a-1|}=g(-a)=\dfrac{1}{1+|1-a|}+\dfrac{1}{1+|-a-1|}$

Since $|1-a|=|a-1|$ and $|-a-1|=|a+1|$, we have shown that the function $g(x)$ is even.

Because $f(x)$ tends to $0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ it remains to see if there any local maxima. There is precisely one in the interval $(1,\infty)$, remember that $f(x)$ is symmetric about $x=1$, and this cusp occurs at $x=2$ **(it remains for you to show this)**. By symmetry, $f(x)$ thus has another local maximum at $x=0$. Since $f(x)$ is bounded, the only two local maxima are indeed the maximum of $f(x)$.

Comment: Note that deleting a post and reposting it again to get rid of unwanted comments is considered abuse of this site!

Comment: Henning, sorry! I realized that I made a typo!!! In haste of others seeing the typo as you did, I wanted to make sure that I reread what I typed and post again. My apologies!